# TRIGGER MYSQL - SERIE Y NUMERO

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema con un *trigger* en MySql. A la hora de realizar un registro, se queda cargando y no pasa de ahí, ni se puede detener tampoco, a menos que detenga el servidor.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `GENERAR_SERIE_CORRELATIVO` AFTER INSERT ON `detalle_matricula_pagos`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        
        Declare serie integer;
        Declare consecutivo integer;
        Declare codigo varchar(14);
        Declare valor varchar(6);
        Declare id integer;
        
        set id = (select MAX(IdDetalleMatriculasPago)  from Detalle_Matricula_Pagos  ORDER BY IdDetalleMatriculasPago DESC LIMIT 1 );

        Set serie = id / 1000000 + 1;

        Set consecutivo = id % 1000000 + Case serie When 1 Then 0 Else 1 End;

        
        Set valor = Cast(serie As varchar(6));

        While (length(valor) < 4) do
            Set valor = '0' + valor;
        end while;
        
        Set codigo = valor;

        Set valor = Cast(consecutivo As varchar(6));
        
        While (length (valor) < 6) do
            Set valor = '0' + valor;
        end while;

        UPDATE Detalle_Matricula_Pagos   SET NEW.CODIGO = CONCAT_WS('-', codigo ,valor)
        WHERE IdDetalleMatriculasPago= id;     
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiré que está usando alguna versión de la serie 8.0.x de MySQL Server.

Algunos comentarios:

- El principal problema parece ser que el disparador (trigger) origina un ciclo infinito y por ello nunca termina. La causa probablemente esté en alguno de los dos (2) ciclos `WHILE`.
- Para concatenar cadenas de texto use la función [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), algo como `Set valor = '0' + valor;` no concatena el texto, es este caso estará sumando, y probablemente aquí está el problema del ciclo infinito. También tiene disponible la función [`LPAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) que puede ser útil en este caso.
- Recuerde que la función [`LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) retorna la longitud de una cadena de texto (string) en bytes. Quizás pueda usar la función [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length).
- Usar `select MAX(IdDetalleMatriculasPago) ...` para obtener el máximo valor de una tabla, usando luego dicho valor para construir un secuencial, no es una práctica recomendada principalmente en situaciones de alta concurrencia porque sería posible que se dupliquen valores. Intente evaluar otras opciones, por ejemplo, con [3.6.9 Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).
- Recuerde que no es necesario el uso de solo letras mayúsculas para plantear las preguntas o cualquier otra interacción en el sitio.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentarios, tenias razon la condicion while estaba mal. y Lpad sirvio demasiado.

Aqui adjunto el script. El problema es que no me funcionaba en un trigger, lo hice en un procedimiento almacenado, Sabes por que no puedo actuaizar una tabla con un trigger despues de insertar.?

Comment: @Carlos: No es posible actualizar (desde el mismo disparador (trigger)) la tabla que desencadenó el disparador (trigger), en tu caso la tabla `Detalle_Matricula_Pagos`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GENERAR_SERIE_NUMERO`()
BEGIN
DECLARE id int;
Declare serie int;
Declare consecutivo int;
Declare codigo nvarchar(14);
Declare valor nvarchar(6);
select MAX(IdDetalleMatriculasPago) INTO id  from Detalle_Matricula_Pagos  ORDER BY IdDetalleMatriculasPago DESC LIMIT 1;
Set serie = id / 1000000 + 1;
Set consecutivo = id % 1000000 + Case serie When 1 Then 0 Else 1 End;
Set valor = cast(serie as varchar(6));
While (CHAR_LENGTH (valor) < 4) DO
    Set valor = LPAD(valor,4,'0')   ;
end WHILE;
Set codigo = valor;
Set valor = Cast(consecutivo As varchar(6));
While (CHAR_LENGTH(valor) < 6) DO
    Set valor = LPAD(valor,6,'0');
end WHILE;
SELECT (CONCAT_ws('-',codigo,valor));

End
```